# How does requirejs make it possible for me to load modules in embedded JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

I recently discovered that I can't embed server-side javascript code (i.e., node.js code) in an html template.  By way of example, I mean that I can't do this:

```
<% var fs = require("fs") %>
```

Someone has suggested that in order to accomplish that feat I would need to use requirejs.  My first reaction would be that I don't see how that could help because requirejs is client-side and I'm trying to embed server-side code.  However, I suspect that the person who gave me the suggestion is probably correct and I note that requirejs claims to work with node.js.  It's just that I have no idea how to use requirejs to get to the promised land.  Can someone please refer me to a link or something that might help me with this?  Thanks.

```
  ... doug
```

Comment: The 2 module patterns (AMD for RequireJS and CommonJS for Node) aren't directly compatible. Each specifies its own API, including different definitions of `require()` and expectations of how it's to be used (with a callback for AMD and return value for CommonJS). You can use other tools, such as Webpack, that are capable of understanding both module patterns at once. (Though, Node's `fs` module depends on extending the V8 engine, which isn't possible client-side. Browsers don't expose the underlying C/C++ layer for extension and not all browser use V8 for it anyways.)

Comment: Wow!  Thanks for the anser (although consderably over my head;).  Cutting to the basics for the moment, it just seems to me that a considerable amount of the utility of being able to embed node.js code in an HTML document is lost if one can't require modules to provide capabilities that can be used in the embedded code.  Now that I'm aware of the issue, I've noticed that I just don't see require statements in embedded node.js code.  Am I missing something?  Is there some other way of approaching this that I should know about?  Thanks

Comment: It's probably just not very common. Having too much logic within a view (EJS or any other) may be considered a code smell. More often, you'll want to perform any extensive logic that uses additional modules within the route handler / controller / etc. and just provide the result as data to the view engine for rendering. Doing that also helps permit reusing the view both client- and server-side, since it only needs to know how to handle the contents of the file rather than how to retrieve it.

Comment: I certainly understand that, when using a MVC approach, one wants to keep as much logic as possible out of the view.  However, I'm not exactly sure what one is supposed to do when not using a MVC approach.  Anyway, thinks for the input.  I need to think about this.